# Triggering workflow within a workflow - Databricks Azure

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

anyone know how do i run another workflow from current workflow that will use same run_parameters that was get from ADF?

Tried to find solution on web but without positive results:(

Please let me know if there is such possibility or do i have create a customized notebook that will do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to implement a wrapper in ADF. You can do this by nesting Execute pipelines activities.

Steps:

1. Create an Execute Pipeline ("MyPipeline") activity and add you required parameters. Set Setting>Invoked pipeline* to your Databricks activity.
2. Create another Execute Pipeline Activity ("Pipeline-Wrapper") which invokes the first "MyPipeline". Setting>Invoked pipeline* set to "MyPipeline".

This way you can invoke different pipelines from the same wrapper whenever you want by just switching the underlying artifact on the wrapper.